# How to increase or decrease alertController's height depending on the height of a view inside of it?

Tags: ios, swift

```
mySecondCustomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
```

mySecondCustomView is the view inside of the UIAlertController. When I set the height of the view is longer than the alertController, it hides the cancel. How could I the cancel button show even after the view's height increases a lot?

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` is an encapsulated content you shouldn't play with it's views and constraints as you will get unexpectable results , you need to make a custom popuoVC

Comment: thank you sir. I'm just trying to make a custom popup view.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)

> **Important**
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support 
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

I would recommend using one of the many alert view libraries instead, e.g. [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView)

Comment: thank you sir. I'm just trying to make a custom popup view.